# Google Maps React Polygon Issues

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson, google-maps-react

I am creating an app that uses wildfire data from APIs and flips it in order to display polygons on a Google Map using the google-maps-react package. I have figured everything out up until returning and displaying the polygon using a function built into the map component. Does anyone want to chime in on what the issue might be? I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Polygon } from 'google-maps-react';



const mapStyles = {
    margin: 30,
    width: '93.75%',
    height: '90%',
    border: '1px solid #3E1C18',
    display: 'inline-block'
};


class FireMap extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            fires: [],
            polygons: []
        }
    }
    

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://services3.arcgis.com/T4QMspbfLg3qTGWY/arcgis/rest/services/Public_Wildfire_Perimeters_View/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ fires: data.features })
                this.state.fires.map((fire) =>{
                    if (fire.geometry !== null){
                        let fireCoords = fire.geometry.rings
                        let trueCoords = []
                        fireCoords.map((coords) => {
                            coords.map((pair) => {
                                let newPair = {lat: pair[1], lng: pair[0]}
                                return trueCoords.push(newPair)
                            })
                        })
                        this.state.polygons.push(trueCoords);
                        console.log(this.state.polygons)
                     }
                 })
            })
    }

    showPolygons = () => {
        this.state.polygons.map((polygon) => {
            let firePoly=  <Polygon paths={polygon} options={{
                fillColor: "#BF5E4B",
                fillOpacity: 0.45,
                strokeColor: "#6B352A",
                strokeOpacity: 0.9,
                strokeWeight: 1
            }}/>
            return firePoly
        })
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="mapBox">
                <Map
                    google={this.props.google}
                    zoom={8}
                    style={mapStyles}
                    initialCenter={{ lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4149 }}
                >
                    {this.showPolygons()}
                </Map>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it render a polygon if you replace `this.state.fires.map(...)` with `some_static_fires_data.map(...)`? And does `new Polygon` instead of `<Polygon>` really work? Also from the docs I've got an impression that it should be `<Polygon fillColor: ...>` not `<Polygon options={{ fillColor: ... }}>`

Comment: @x00 I tried using the angle brackets but it wasn't working. I changed the code to use the console to confirm that my polygon was accepting the true coords for the paths attribute and that a polygon value was being created, but it doesn't seem to be getting returned. I am so stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't caught from your comment if you've tried things I've suggested... But you've edited your post with some random (and incorrect) changes. OK, I'll try to post an answer. It's an answer related to the original code because it looks simpler and contains less errors.

This is how I think it should look like:

```
const coord_pair_to_latlng =  ([lat,lng]) => ({ lat, lng })
const convert_ring_coords = ring => ring.map(coord_pair_to_latlng)

class FireMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { fires: [] }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://services3.arcgis.com/T4QMspbfLg3qTGWY/arcgis/rest/services/Public_Wildfire_Perimeters_View/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ fires: data.features }))
  }
  displayFires = () => this.state.fires
    .filter(fire => fire.geometry !== null)
    .map(fire => fire.geometry.rings)
    .map(rings => <Polygon 
      paths = { rings.reduce((acc, ring) => acc.concat(convert_ring_coords(ring)), []) }
      fillColor     = "#BF5E4B"
      fillOpacity   = {0.45}
      strokeColor   = "#6B352A"
      strokeOpacity = {0.9}
      strokeWeight  = {1}
    />)
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mapBox">
        <Map
          google        = {this.props.google}
          zoom          = {8}
          style         = {mapStyles}
          initialCenter = {{ lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4149 }}
        >
          {this.displayFires()}
        </Map>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Except for a more functional code style (which you can ignore), basically all I've changed was:

1. `new Polygon()` and `<Polygon>` is not the same thing. You should return the latter. JSX translates to something like `React.createElement(Polygon,...)` not to `new Polygon(...)`. OK, you've fixed that.
2. **As per [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#polygon) and per [source code](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/71d19a5b9b74d4330fb7d1b8e3b8d8ab94647ff7/src/components/Polygon.js#L45)**, `Polygon` should be created as

   ```js
   <Polygon
     paths         = {coords}
     fillColor     = "#BF5E4B"
     fillOpacity   = {0.45}
     strokeColor   = "#6B352A"
     strokeOpacity = {0.9}
     strokeWeight  = {1}
   />
   ```

   and not as

   ```js
   <Polygon
     paths         = {coords}
     options       = {{...}}
   />
   ```

   **your `options` are ignored**
3. `this.displayFires()` in `componentDidMount` does nothing, so it should be removed.

   <sup>As a side note: also at the time of `this.displayFires()` call `this.state` [is not changed yet](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-doesnt-react-update-thisstate-synchronously). But it shouldn't change the outcome because, as I said, `this.displayFires()` have no effect in `componentDidMount`... but `this.state.polygons.push` in your new version of code can have an effect... or I'd better say *will introduce bugs*. You should never do that.</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still getting an error when I try to export this component using the code provided, looks like some punctuation is missing.EDIT: You forgot a closing '/' for the Polygon. Going to try this now.

Comment: This answer works! The API I was using originally didn't work, which I neglected to mention was the reason for changing the code and tinkering with it, but hallelujah! The polygons display perfectly. Huge thanks to you x00, gonna try even more stuff with hover and then hopefully deployment.